# How I can hide php error details from end users

Tags: php, apache, xampp

how I can hide php error details from end users
I don't want the end users see my php error details

I modify on php.ini

```
display_errors = off
```

and I modify in .htaccess

```
php_flag display_errors off
```

and i restart Apache server
but still the error display

I use xampp v3.2.4
[image: screnshot of the error]

Comment: We're programmers, we can read. Please read about [why you shouldn’t upload images of code or errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: If you configure your vhost to write into error.log you don't need to touch php.ini, because display_errors are off by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting following code at the start of your file to stop display error's in runtime

```
// Turn off all error reporting for your production environment
error_reporting(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not supposed to hide the error, you are supposed to fix it so it does not happen again. The message tells you that interior_image_name2 is missing from your table.

From what I can tell your SQL query throws an error, and at this point you application cannot continue because your expected result does not exist.
You either fix your SQL, or you try/catch to see if you have an result before you attempt to work with it.

Comment: *"You are not supposed to hide the error"* Yes you are. Don't display error messages to end users, but log them